# Autodesk Forge Api - Can't get account names

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is there any chance to get a list of account ids and account names?
I know I can use https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs endpoint to get hub ids and then I can convert them to account ids but still I have no idea how to get account names.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

GET hubs
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-GET/

Its response includes hubs name under:
data.attributes.name

Comment: I think hub name and account name are not equal.
I mean the value I get from the API(hubs GET) is different than the value I see in the application(Account dropdown in the project form).

Can I get this value somehow?